# Rabbitvcs not showing lock owner

Tags: linux, ubuntu, subversion

I have installed rabbitvcs in my ubuntu 14.04 system. It's working well in it. But it's not showing the file lock owner when locking some already locked file. It just says failed lock.

As I show in tortoisesvn it's shows the user who has locked that file.

Here I am attaching screenshot also. Please help me if any solution or alternatives are there for this problem.

[image: RabbitVCS_Lock_problem]